# Free or low-cost CRM-like SaaS recommendation for student-run nonprofit

Tags: web-apps, web-services, saas

I'm one of the heads of a German nationwide student-run nonprofit initiative that provides free tutoring to refugees and children from underprivileged families.

We built our own backend running on our own server with a custom web interface to allow our chapters located in University town's all over Germany to manage our database of students (children in school) and tutors (young adults in university) as well as connections between them. However, the software hasn't been updated in years and feels rather clunky at this point.

Since all our work is done on a volunteer basis, no one has the time nor the resources to rewrite this software from scratch nor to get familiar with and update the old one.

But perhaps there is no need for that. We wrote our own software in a time when 'SaaS' wasn't a thing yet and the Internet in general was much less saturated than it is today. Can someone recommend a service that might be able to suit our needs?

It would have to do all of the following:

- allow logins for on the order of 100 users (our chapter heads)
- be free or at least cost less than, say, 500 €/yr
- allow our users to interact with (usually different parts of) the same database of students and tutors
- allow CRUD operations on connections between students and tutors
- ideally keep a log of all CRUD ops
- be GDPR compliant

Perhaps there might a CRM SaaS or something of the sort that can accommodate this set of requirements? Any suggestions are welcome!